# How to display year-month accurately on X-axis for plotly chart?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I am trying to find a solution to accurately display the X-axis for my plotly chart.

Here is my code -

```
import pandas as pd

print(pd.__version__) # 1.2.4

import plotly
print(plotly.__version__) # 5.5.0
```

I create a data frame with `year_month` as object type and `p95_gbs` as float type for my metrics (Y-axis).

```
import plotly.express as px
df = pd.DataFrame({"year_month" : ["2023-01", "2023-02", "2023-03"], "p95_gbs" : [20.5,22.2,23.9]})
df.head()
```

[image]

Here is my code to do the monthly line chart

```
hover_data = ['year_month','p95_gbs']
fig = px.line(data_frame=df, x="year_month", y="p95_gbs", hover_data = hover_data)
fig.update_yaxes(rangemode = "tozero")
fig.show()
```

As of now, the code does not show only 3 data points that are present at `year-month` level. Instead the line chart gives a false impression that there are more than 3 data points which is not the case.

Ideally, my X-axis should only show 3 data points - `2023-01, 2023-02, 2023-03`.

In general, if I have 2 years worth of data, then I would expect to have 24 points (12 points per month). The format that I want in the output is `YYYY-MONTHNAME`.

How can I tweak my figure to display this year-month information accurately ?

[image]

I have also tried to update the layout using `xaxis_tickformat` but still the chart does not display accurate information on X-axis

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(
    x = df['year_month'],
    y = df['p95_gbs'],
))
fig.update_layout(
    title = 'Time Series with YearMonth on X-axis',
    xaxis_tickformat = '%Y-%B'
)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @QuangHoang - thank you for the inputs, but these are matplotlib tickers. Can you help with a working code solution?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I did not read it carefully. I have no idea how plotly works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since plotly uses the D3 format for time series notation, set 'M1' in the dtick field if you want to display the time series in units of one month. See https://plotly.com/python/time-series/#configuring-tick-labels for details.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(
    x = df['year_month'],
    y = df['p95_gbs'],
))
fig.update_layout(title = 'Time Series with YearMonth on X-axis')
fig.update_xaxes(tickformat = '%Y-%B', dtick='M1')

fig.show()
```

[image]